# Unable to interact with other contracts because Tezos.get_contract_opt got None

Tags: smart-contracts, ligo

I tried to interact with other contracts but failed because `Tezos.get_contract_opt` always returns `None`. Here's the demo code (ligo v0.60.0):

**receiver.jsligo** - A contract that the "broadcaster" contract will call. It has a `nat` var which will be increased by 1 whenever it's called.

```
type Storage = {
  signal_received: nat,
};

type Parameter =
  | ["Ping"];

type Return = [list<operation>, Storage];

const main = (ep: Parameter, store: Storage): Return =>
  match(ep, {
    Ping: (_p) => [
      list([]),
      {
        ...store,
        signal_received: store.signal_received + (1 as nat)
      }
    ],
  });
```

**broadcaster.jsligo** - A contract that will call the "receiver" contract

```
type Storage = unit;

type Parameter =
  | ["Ping_receiver"];

type Return = [list<operation>, Storage];

const ping_receiver = (_p: unit, store: Storage) => {
  // [[[ put the receiver contract address here ]]]
  const addr = "KT1EjK4pKLeVYdhSx1LNKj6j9jGMxn8e4mGs" as address;
  const receiverContract =
    match(Tezos.get_contract_opt(addr), {
      Some: contract => contract,
      None: () => failwith("Receiver contract not found.")
    });
  const op = Tezos.transaction(
    ["ping"],
    0 as tez,
    receiverContract
  );
  return [list([op]), store]
};

const main = (ep: Parameter, store: Storage): Return =>
  match(ep, {
    Ping_receiver: (p: unit) => ping_receiver(p, store),
  });
```

I used `taquito` to originate the contracts. The overall flow was:

1. compile and originate the receiver contract
2. put the newly originated receiver contract address in the broadcaster contract
3. compile and originate the broadcaster contract

I ran into the "Receiver contract not found." error when trying to test out the broadcaster contract on Better Call Dev. But it works fine when interacting with the receiver contract directly.

- [The receiver contract](https://better-call.dev/ghostnet/KT1EjK4pKLeVYdhSx1LNKj6j9jGMxn8e4mGs) (Ghostnet)
- [The broadcaster contract](https://better-call.dev/ghostnet/KT1JDTL154JbQGJjRU4dkHtmiyMuQydHr7hA) (Ghostnet)

The source code can be found at https://github.com/caaatisgood/ligo-inter-contract-invocation as well as the deployment script [here](https://github.com/caaatisgood/ligo-inter-contract-invocation/blob/main/deploy/index.ts).

Comment: Turns out it was because the receive contract has parameter `unit`, while I'm expecting a contract that has string as parameter in the broadcaster contract. Addressed in https://github.com/caaatisgood/ligo-inter-contract-invocation/commit/7b4475945fde032b6df5521b870b150b7533a24f

Comment: Kudos to Exequiel from LIGO discord!